# winforms visual studio installer License agreement problem

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, installation

I've having trouble adding a rtf file to license agreement installation window, does anyone have any tips to get it working. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Installer is based on Windows Installer which uses a really ancient RichText control.  Basically if you can get WordPad/Write on Windows XP to properly display the file it should work correctly in your install.

Comment: thanks but I have windows wordpad compatible rft. I've browsed added the file for the application Data folder, still nothing shows up.

Comment: Then try it with Windows 95 wordpad.  And yes, Windows Installer is really that old. :-(